# @fontface both otf and ttf are not working at Firefox, but work with Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, firefox, css, font-face

I have this font that I want to use it. I uploaded it to my server, and use fontface to call it. They work great at Chrome and Safari, but not at all in FireFox. I tried both .otf and .ttf. They all work with Chrome ans Safari but not FireFox. They do also work with jsfiddle.net. I googled why is FireFox doing this, people say if I convert .ttf to .otf, it should work. But it is not working now. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with it?

```
     <!doctype html>
     <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>font-test</title>
    <style>
    @font-face {font-family:Hush;  src: local(Hush),       url('http://www.yifanchen.net/temp/Hush.otf') format('opentype');}
      @font-face {font-family:Hush2;  src: local(Hush2), url('http://www.yifanchen.net/temp/hush.ttf') format('truetype');}

   .test h1.otf {font-family:Hush; color:#000;} 
   .test h1.ttf {font-family:Hush2; color:red;}
   </style>
   </head>

   <body>
    <div class="test"> 
   <h1 class="otf">This is a test for Hush.otf.</h1>
   <h1 class="ttf">This is a test for Hush.ttf</h1>
   </div>
   </body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7537247/wUvqe/ 
They do work at jsfddle, if you want to test it in FireFox. You probably need to download it.

Comment: Is the page linking to these fonts on www.yifanchen.net ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, the path has to be in the same domin. Firefox can't locate any fontface if you set up the src url to another domin. I changed the domin, it works at FireFox, and it works in IE too. Just hope this answer helps other users too.

Answer (score 0):

Getting fonts to work across all browsers is pretty fiddly, and will require some additional formats if you also want to support Internet Explorer.  If you can find the same or similar font at http://fontsquirrel.com, they have a very simple "font-face kit" download that you just copy into your site.  Or you could use their template as a guide, and substitute your font.